# NUnit console run all categories (where: cat = ' ')

Tags: jenkins, nunit, nunit-3.0, nunit-console

I have a suite of NUnit tests and I am using Jenkins and MSBuild to run them. I have a number of test categories and sometimes I want to run just one category and other times all of them. Category parameter is provided from Jenkins.

I have a problem when I want to run all categories. If category is not provided I get this condition `where: cat==` and build fails.
If category is provided everything is fine.
Is there a way to tell nunit console to run all tests categories? Something like `where: cat==*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NUnit console option `--where` takes an argument written in Test Selection Language. (TSL) Like any other computer language, it has it's own syntax and you get errors if you don't follow it. The expression `cat==` is not legal TSL. It's just as if you wrote `if (cat==)` in a C# program.

If you don't want to do any category selection, then you should simply not use `cat==` in your where clause. If you don't want to do any selection at all but just to run all tests, then you shouldn't be using `--where` on the command-line.

If Jenkins is actually **creating** the command-line for you, then you have to figure out how to tell it to **not use** the `--where` option. I don't use Jenkins, but I would bet that there docs tell you how to do it. Most CI systems I have used do it by simply not filling anything in the space where you enter categories.